# Group, summarize and transpose

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ctgroup (dataframe)

Camera Trap Name  Animal Name         a_sum 
 1  CAM27             Chicken             1
 2  CAM27             Dog                 1
 3  CAM27             Dog                 4
 4  CAM28             Cat                 3
 5  CAM28             Dog                 22
 6  CAM28             Dog                 1
```

*a_sum = No. of animals recorded in a camera

So essentially I want to - Group by 2 fields(Camera Trap Name, Scientific Name) and then Count the number of record in the column "a_sum", and transpose the data so that Animal. Name becomes column and Camera Trap Name my rows. I want to display all the animal names in columns, with 0 if no data available
i.e.,

```
Camera trap name        Dog   Cat   Wolf   Chicken
   CAM28                 23     4     1      4
   CAM27                 5      0     0      4
```

I tried using the following code

```
dcast (ctgroup, Camera.Trap.name + Animal.name, value.var  = "a_sum")
```

And I got the following error:

```
In dcast(ctgroup, Camera.Trap.name + Scientific.name, value.var = "a_sum") :
  The dcast generic in data.table has been passed a grouped_df and will attempt to redirect to the reshape2::dcast; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. Please do this redirection yourself like reshape2::dcast(ctgroup). In the next version, this warning will become an error.
```

I don't think I know enough to construct the correct code for carrying out this work.

Comment: Its easier for the community if you provide your sample data in a transposable way, like with `dput()`

Comment: Try `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarize()` and then `tidyr::pivot_wider()`. If you take a glance at the help file for each it should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ctgroup %>%
  group_by(Camera, Animal) %>%
  summarize(a_sum = sum(a_sum)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Camera, names_from = Animal, values_from = a_sum, values_fill = list(a_sum = 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

With data.table ...

```
# Load data.table.
require(data.table)

# Create data.set.
df <- data.frame(Camera = c("CAM27", "CAM27", "CAM27", "CAM28", "CAM28", "CAM28"),
Animal = c("Chicken", "Dog", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog"),
a_sum = c(1, 1, 4, 3, 22, 1))

# Set the data.frame as a data.table.
setDT(df)

# Cast by `Camera` and `Animal` and sum `a_sum`.
dcast(df, Camera ~ Animal, value.var = "a_sum", fun.aggregate = sum)
#    Camera Cat Chicken Dog
# 1:  CAM27   0       1   5
# 2:  CAM28   3       0  23

# If you want to coerce back to a data.frame.
setDF(df)
```

Comment: I used the dplyr approach instead and that was a little more easy than entering individual camera trap information because I have a hundred data points. But thank you Khaynes

Comment: that makes no sense

Comment: @KeerthiKrutha I don't think they intended for you to have to type in all the observations in order to create the data frame, I think they did that because you didn't include the data in your question in a format that can be copy-pasted directly into R. If you've already got the data, start this code at `setDT`

Comment: @camille: Oh! I dint know that... thank you :), I am super young to R and still holding hands to walk through it.